# How to send email reliably

Tags: email

I'm sending about 5000 transactional emails a month to various users. Things like password reset emails and other notifications - never any spam.

I'm currently using mailgun where I have a shared IP. What's happening is, about one a month my emails get blocked as spam as some other user on the IP is sending spam. I'm not talking about going to their spam folder - it gets blocked completely.

I then open a support ticket and they give me a new IP, but still a number of emails do not get delivered.

I don't mind paying for a dedicated IP, but they say at less than 50 000 emails a week a dedicated IP can have even lower deliverability.

What do you suggest I use for sending emails reliably?

Comment: This question asks for a service to send emails. The service part if more important than the software part in this question. It is thus off-topic per https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2713/are-questions-for-service-providers-welcome-at-our-site

Comment: Where can I ask about sending service?

Comment: Stack Exchange does not have any site for this, but you can try Quora or Reddit, or some specialist forum.

Answer (score 2):

I think [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com) have all you need:

- List item
- send a huge og email (million+ emails/mo)
- API features
- dedicated IP
- CRM integration
- and you can try for free

They work with the [biggest](https://sendgrid.com/customers/) companies!